# Call PHP Class method using variable instead of actual function name

Tags: php, class

I am having a problem with accessing Class methods using variable instead of function name. Like in below example:

```
class Test
{
    public static function route()
    {
        $functionName = "myFunction";
        echo self::$functionName;

    }

    public static function myFunction()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I am getting error message:

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Test::$functionName
```

Is there a way of accessing class methods using variables containing function name? 
Please help :)

Comment: `self::$functionName()`

Comment: Silly me, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a function usually done with `()`. So you have to add `()` to your `echo self::$functionName;` so it will become:

```
public static function route()
{
    $functionName = "myFunction";
    echo self::$functionName();
}
```